# how to avoid linebreakers from unicode string read from text file in python

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode

How do I remove line breakers  i.e. '\n' from a unicode text read from text file using python? Also, how do I test if values of a list is linebreaker or not in unicode string?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Checks if the text is more than 0 symbols. And if the last symbol is "\n"
if len(test) > 0 and test[-1:]=="\n":
    # If so, remove the last linebreak
    test = test[0:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing newlines from a text file, you can use rstrip():

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         print(line.rstrip())
```

To test if a value is a linebreak:

```
for item in some_values:
    if item == '\n':
        do something
```

Alternately, you can test if '\n' is in a line:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
           if '\n' in line:
                print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Unicode strings have the same methods as standard strings, you can remove '\n' with line.replace(r'\n','') and check if it exists with '\n' in unc